# Multiple results when identifying

Tags: acrcloud

When IDing the song "Love Invaders - Fatima Yamah" I get the below results:

```
python test.py ~/MusicID/File5.mp3
```

https://pastebin.com/YAdAru7A

None of which are actually correct, although some of the scores report 100. How can one song report back so many results? Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out this issue, it seems we don't have the song "Love Invaders - Fatima Yamah" in our database (but we've added it), we are looking to the issue of score 100. You can try again now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks, however it still isn't returning that song ID? Still results in numerous different IDs.

Comment: Hi Joe, Could you please send the audio file you want to recognize to us? support@acrcloud.com, we will look into this issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi, it's being recognised now, however still returning numerous results for the file:
https://pastebin.com/65raLKiR

Comment: Hi Joe, the system returns multiple results by default, but you can pick the first one as the best result.